# Return Mobile Number, IP Address and Date Format in PHP String using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to return following data from given string

1. IP Address
2. Mobile Number
3. Is any date present

Input:

> rahul shinde 11.23.52.26 rshinde@gmail.com 12/5/2014 testing string 9856245136 12.26.5.56 7756231586 Testing 12/5/1991

Output:

> IP: 11.23.52.26, 12.26.5.56
>   Date : 12/5/2014, 12/5/1991
>   Mobile No: 9856245136 7756231586

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex to extract all ipaddresses, phone number, dates.

```
(?<ipaddress>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})|(?<Phonenumber>\d{10})|(?<Date>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/7)

Comment: next time don't forget to show your attempts  otherwise your question would be downvoted.